# How to Add seprate Loader file on a onClick event button on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React JS still learning a lot. I created another js file (Loading.js) which is I want it to be a loader on my onClick event specifically on (New Client button) && (Manage Account button)

```
import React from 'react';
import Loading from './Loading';
import '../Styles.scss';
    Modal,
    Icon,
} from 'semantic-ui-react';

function InvestNow() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={() => {
          window.location.href = '/';
          //* ADD Loading.js here
        }}
        color="yellow"
        fluid
        icon
        labelPosition="left">
        <Icon name="plus" />
        New Client
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InvestNow
```

This is the Loader I created from react-loader-spinner

**My Loading.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Loader from 'react-loader-spinner';
import '../Styles.scss';
import 'react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css';

class Loading extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Loader
        type="Bars"
        color="#FFD400"
        height={450}
        width={100}
        timeout={5000} //3 secs
        className="Loadingstyle"
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Loading;
```

Comment: So on click you want to display a loading animation? This can be done by creating a state in `InvestNow` component to track whether or not the loading should be shown `const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);` you can then set loading to true in your click `setLoading(true)`; To display your loader you can conditionally display it using `{ !!loading && <Loading /> }`

Comment: yes right @JacobSmit

Comment: do you use router ?  do you use redux mobx or any other state manage library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you want is to maintain a state to toggle loading indicator. For that import "useState" from react. And then use the below code as reference.

```
<Button
onClick={() => {
    setLoading(true);
    setTimeout(function(){ 
       setLoading(false);
       window.location.href='/';
    }, 5000);
}}
>
    {isLoading ? <Loading /> : null }
    <Icon name="plus" />
    New Client
</Button>
```

You also need to maintain state to handle toggling loading indicator. Inside "InvestNow" function write this code.

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for having your time to answer. I think my question is Misleading Sorry for that. This would be the sequence: After I click the button, my Loader will appear ( which is I set for 5sec) then will redirect to another js file. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to show your `Loading.js` component instead of the button after `onClick` is called. If so, you actually need to add an state management to your component. Something like

```js
function InvestNow() {
  // Variable to control whether you should render loading or button
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      {
        // Will render Button when not loading, and Loading component otherwise
        !isLoading ? (
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              // Sets loading to true
              setIsLoading(true)

              // Do other things
            }}
            /* ... */
          />
        ) : (
          <Loading
            /* ... */
          />
        )
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

For `React.useState` reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate